# React Native IAP method requestSubscription gives 'Invalid Product Id' warning and nothing happens in ios and android

Tags: react-native, in-app-purchase, react-native-iap

Package used : react-native-iap  version-9.0.0-rc.4
We have below things done -
1.Agreements , tax and banking completed.
2.Xcode capabilities and certificate
3.In app store the in app purchase option is selected for the application
4.Added sandbox testers and logged in the real device with the same sandbox account in app store.
5.Added subscriptions.